# MATLAB 3D volume visualization

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `M, 135*191*121 double` and want to plot it in 3D volume by using those 121 slices. How can I do this? (I need a grayscale image)

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [vol3d v2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22940-vol3d-v2) , it an update to Joe Conti's vol3d function, allowing voxel colors and alpha values to be defined explicitly.  In cases where voxels can be any RGB color, use:

```
 vol3d('CData', cdata);
```

where cdata is an MxNxPx3 array, with RGB color along the 4th dimension. In cases where color and alpha values are highly independent, specify an MxNxP alphamatte as follows:

```
vol3d('CData', cdata, 'Alpha', alpha);
```

Comment: thanks for the useful tipp @natan! I was wondering how to label the axes properly? after calling to `xlabel|ylabel|zlabel` the desired text is not displayed on the `axes`, especially after rotating the volume. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

if you have 3 arrays, storing (x,y,z) coordinates of every point that you need to plot, then you can use function plot3
From matlab help

> PLOT3  Plot lines and points in 3-D space.
>       PLOT3() is a three-dimensional analogue of PLOT().
>
> ```
> PLOT3(x,y,z), where x, y and z are three vectors of the same length,
> plots a line in 3-space through the points whose coordinates are the
> elements of x, y and z.
>
> PLOT3(X,Y,Z), where X, Y and Z are three matrices of the same size,
> plots several lines obtained from the columns of X, Y and Z.
>
> Various line types, plot symbols and colors may be obtained with
> PLOT3(X,Y,Z,s) where s is a 1, 2 or 3 character string made from
> the characters listed under the PLOT command.
>
> PLOT3(x1,y1,z1,s1,x2,y2,z2,s2,x3,y3,z3,s3,...) combines the plots
> defined by the (x,y,z,s) fourtuples, where the x's, y's and z's are
> vectors or matrices and the s's are strings.
>
> Example: A helix:
>
>     t = 0:pi/50:10*pi;
>     plot3(sin(t),cos(t),t);
>
> PLOT3 returns a column vector of handles to lineseries objects, one
> handle per line. The X,Y,Z triples, or X,Y,Z,S quads, can be 
> followed by parameter/value pairs to specify additional 
> properties of the lines.
> ```

for 3d plots you may also want to look into surf function

Comment: I could not find right snytax to visualize my `M`. Whatever I tried, it gave me warning. Could you please tell me what should I use?